# How to print more than one record in Table from database with URL

Tags: java, android

I am trying to print the data from a URL in Table but I'm only able to print the one record. I need all the records those are available

I do the following:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Intent myNewIntent=getIntent();


        URL url = null;

        try {
            url = new URL("http://192.168.59.1:8080/WebApplication2/cegepgim/mobile/message");

            HttpURLConnection client = null;

            client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            client.setRequestMethod("GET");

            int responseCode = client.getResponseCode();

            System.out.println("\n Sending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);

            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            InputStreamReader myInput = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(myInput);
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            System.out.println("The response is " + response.toString());

            JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
            JSONArray jsonArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("message");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject message = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                message_id =""+message.getInt ("message_id");
                sender_id =""+message.getInt ("sender_id");
                receiver_id =""+message.getInt("receiver_id");
                message_content = message.getString("message_content");
                message_date = message.getString("message_date");

            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


        tr1 = new TableRow(Main3Activity.this);
        mszid = new TextView(Main3Activity.this);
        mszid.setText(message_id);
        tr1.addView(mszid);


        sendid = new TextView(Main3Activity.this);
        sendid.setText(sender_id);
        tr1.addView(sendid);

        receid = new TextView(Main3Activity.this);
        receid.setText(receiver_id);
        tr1.addView(receid);

        mszcontent = new TextView(Main3Activity.this);
        mszcontent.setText(message_content);
        tr1.addView(mszcontent);

        mszdate = new TextView(Main3Activity.this);
        mszdate.setText(message_date);
        tr1.addView(mszdate);

        myTable1.addView(tr1);

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

The program runs and print the first record, but there are 5 records that I'm trying to print. As it's printing out of the loop so it's not printing all records. I'm not sure how to print in Table with loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should be saving all the records in the first place. Here's your problem,

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject message = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                message_id =""+message.getInt ("message_id");
                sender_id =""+message.getInt ("sender_id");
                receiver_id =""+message.getInt("receiver_id");
                message_content = message.getString("message_content");
                message_date = message.getString("message_date");

            }
```

In this code, you are actually over-writing the previously parsed valued from the previous JSON object. Eventually, what you are printing is the last record.

You should use an ArrayList and save all the records and then display them in your table using a for loop on the ArrayList.